# display tag in html not working for the html email template

Tags: html, css, gmail, media-queries, email-templates

I am working on an email template for my company. Depending on whether its a mobile or a browser I am trying to display the content.

The display attribute doesnot seem to work with gmail,I cannot paste the entire code here. this is the media query I use.

```
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 380px) {
    .mobileWidth {
      width: 290px !important; 
    }

    img { 
    max-width: 130px !important;
    max-height: 130px !important;
    }   

    .right {
      width: 100% !important;         
      position: relative !important;
    }       

     .test {
       width: 290px !important;
       text-align: center !important;
     }

     .showMobile {
       display:inline !important;
     }

    .hideMobile {
      display: none;
    }           
  } 

<html>
  <body>
    <!-- this div block is intended to by default not show in the browser and show in the mobile -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class = "showMobile" style ="display:none;">
            <p> some text and image <p>
          </div>

          <!-- this div block is intended to be shown in the browser and not shown in the mobile -->

          <div class="hideMobile">
            <p> some other text and image </p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine in the iphone mail account but doesnot work for the gmail browser and nor the gmail app for iphone. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, `display:none` will be stripped away in Gmail.  The best way to work around this is to use set the inline style to `float:left, width:0px, height:0px, visibility:none, overflow:hidden`.  When you meet the requirements for the media query, you revert all of these styles, so within your media query you can set `float:none !important, overflow:visible !important, width:(actual width or 100%) !important, height:(same as width) !important`

Answer (score 0):

For HTML emails it's advised that you don't use css styles in the way you are doing.

You should use an old school table based layout and older (but still valid) html tags etc.

CSs styles should be kept to a minimum and only used as inline styles.

Comment: #Billy I have edited the question to be a similar to original html structure.

Comment: That's great but you're still using DIVs in there and you still have all that CSS. Here's an article on html emails that's well worth a read: http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: I use inline CSS and not an external file